# zsh equivalent of bash show-all-if-ambiguous?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

In bash, if you hit tab when there are multiple possible completions you get a list of matches that keeps reprinting if you repeatedly press tab. In tcsh, setting autocomplete to enhanced also achieves this.

In zsh, you do get the list of matches, but on 2nd, 3rd tab press it starts cycling through matches. Is there a way to get zsh to do the equivalent of bash's show-all-if-ambiguous without the cycling?

I'm not looking for the clever but useless "why would you press tab several times if it displayed after the first?". If I had been able to adjust my habits I'd have done so by now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zsh has a lot of [completion-related options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#SEC103) (see `man zshoptions` under `Completion`). I think you're after `setopt no_auto_menu` and perhaps `setopt bash_auto_list` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased my question badly. I want to know how to disable tab completion cycling. I think I'll start a new question.

Comment: @user714112: `setopt no_auto_menu` does disable tab completion cycling: if you press `Tab` and the current prefix is ambiguous, you see a menu, and that's it, the command line won't change.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I'm not sure why I didn't see that earlier. Is it possible to get it to redisplay the list on 2nd, 3rd, 4th TAB instead of nothing? Human instinct is to think your keyboard isn't working if nothing happens on 2nd, 3rd, 4th tab keypress.

Comment: @user7000: Again, it does redisplay the list each time you press `Tab`. If I clear the screen from the terminal emulator menu, or create a file, then press `Tab` again, zsh redisplays the list and shows the new file. (Just tested with zsh 4.3.4, and I don't think that behavior has changed in a long time.)

Comment: I finally got the solution. I needed your 2 options plus removing ALWAYS_LAST_PROMPT. So this gives me the elusive behavior I wanted: setopt bash_auto_list;
setopt no_auto_menu;
unsetopt ALWAYS_LAST_PROMPT;  Once again, thank you for helping me out with this. I appreciate your persistence

Comment: Could someone point me to the documentation for no_auto_menu? I can't find it anywhere online (and my command line apropos NEVER finds anything useful).

Comment: @user7000 `man zshoptions`, or online in the page I linked. Search for `auto_menu` — options beginning with `no_` are mechanically built opposites.

Comment: Thanks very much Gilles. And I didn't know about the no_ convention.